# How to display managed objects with certain value in one of the fields in WinDbg using SOS (or SOSEX)?

Tags: debugging, windbg, sos, sosex

My problem is this:

```
0:000> !DumpHeap -type Microsoft.Internal.ReadLock -stat
------------------------------
Heap 0
total 0 objects
------------------------------
Heap 1
total 0 objects
------------------------------
Heap 2
total 0 objects
------------------------------
Heap 3
total 0 objects
------------------------------
total 0 objects
Statistics:
              MT    Count    TotalSize Class Name
000007fef3d14088    74247      2375904 Microsoft.Internal.ReadLock
Total 74247 objects
```

The way I read this output is that I have 74,247 `Microsoft.Internal.ReadLock` instances on my heap. However, some of them are probably pending collection.

I want to display only those which are not pending collection.

For example, `0000000080f88e90` is the address of one of these objects and it is garbage. I know it, because:

```
0:000> !mroot 0000000080f88e90
No root paths were found.
0:000> !refs 0000000080f88e90 -target
Objects referencing 0000000080f88e90 (Microsoft.Internal.ReadLock):
NONE
0:000> !do 0000000080f88e90
Name:        Microsoft.Internal.ReadLock
MethodTable: 000007fef3d14088
EEClass:     000007fef3c63410
Size:        32(0x20) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ComponentModel.Composition\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
Fields:
              MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr            Value Name
000007fef3d13fb0  400001e        8 ...oft.Internal.Lock  0 instance 0000000080001010 _lock
000007fef0a8c7d8  400001f       10         System.Int32  1 instance                1 _isDisposed
```

As one can see, both `sosex.mroot` and `sosex.refs` indicate no one references it, plus dumping its fields reveals that it was disposed through `IDisposable`, so it makes sense that the object is garbage (I know that being disposed does not imply the object is garbage, but it is in this case).

Now I want to display all those instances which are not garbage. I guess I am to use the `.foreach` command. Something like this:

```
.foreach(entry {!dumpheap -type Microsoft.Internal.ReadLock -short}){.if (???) {.printf "%p\n", entry} }
```

My problem is that I have no idea what goes into the `.if` condition.

I am able to inspect the _isDisposed field like this:

```
0:000> dd 0000000080f88e90+10 L1
00000000`80f88ea0  00000001
```

But `.if` expects an expression and all I have is a command output. If I knew how to extract information from the command output and arrange it as an expression then I could use it as the `.if` condition and be good.

So, my question is this - is there a way to get the field value as an expression suitable for `.if`? Alternatively, is it possible to parse the command output in a way suitable for using the result as the `.if` condition?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't have an example which uses ReadLock objects, but I tried with Strings and this is my result:

```
.foreach (entry {!dumpheap -short -type Microsoft.Internal.ReadLock}) 
{ 
    .if (poi(${entry}+10) == 1)  
    {
         .printf "%p\n", ${entry}
    }
}
```

I'm using poi() to get pointer size data from the address. Also note I'm using *${entry}* not *entry* in both, poi() and .printf. You might also like !do ${entry} inside the .if.

In one line for copy/paste:

```
.foreach (entry {!dumpheap -short -type Microsoft.Internal.ReadLock}) {.if (poi(${entry}+10) == 1) {.printf "%p\n", ${entry}}}
```

Comment: This answers my question. Do you know how can I .if on the result of the `!mroot` or `!refs` command? Although, testing the value of `_isDisposable` is enough in this case, it may not be so for other objects, where the only reliable way is to check if the object is rooted. Meaning running a command like `!mroot` or `!refs` or something similar. But then, how to .if on the result?

Comment: @mark: I've seen your question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20766554/dumping-only-rooted-managed-objects-and-or-statistics-on-them-inside-windbg regarding this topic. I can think of a very ugly solution which might not work with the next version of SOSEX any more. I'll explain it there.